# Ionic 3 with ngx-translate - Lazy loaded

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, lazy-loading, multilingual, ngx-translate

I'm trying to integrate the ngx-translate plugin into my Ionic 3 project with lazy loading. I've followed the guide on the Ionic Framework website.

The default language loads but using `translate.use()` has no effect at all.

I've posted the project on gitbub and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the link to the repo: 
https://github.com/sumodevelopment/ngx-translate-test

Comment: here solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691028/ngx-translation-issue-with-ionic-3-app/44698964

Comment: you can accept answer, for same i did post answer on ionic community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your `home.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [Http]
      }
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    HomePage
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

And there no need to use `TranslateService` Provider in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: I'll be checking this out in this week. I will updated this comment when I've tried it out.

Comment: When I try to import @angular/http i get a new error: 

`Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'.`

Everytime I use Ionic I get a new issue. It's becoming quite frustrating.

Comment: try to use `@angular/http` instead `@angular/common/http`

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours to get it working. Finally, I had to add `HttpClientModule` to the import section of `app.module.ts` (in your case maybe it's - `home.module.ts`). Hope that helps.

First: Import `HttpClientModule`
Second: Use `HttpClient` instead of `Http`.

So, the code is as follow: `app.module.ts` (In your case `home.module.ts`)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';

//translate related imports
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HomePage,
    ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
    HttpClientModule
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    })
  ],
  exports: [
     HomePage
  ]
})

export class HomePageModule {}
```

In `app.component.ts` add this line in `constructor`.

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
...
translate.setDefaultLang('en');//So English language set
```

And then you have to create two `JSON` files in `./assets/i18n/` path.

`en.JSON`

```
{
   "title": "Translation demo",
   "text": "This is a simple demonstration app for {{value}}"
}
```

Then use in your app with `PIPE` filter like this.

```
<h1>{{'title' | translate}}</h1>
```

OR

```
<h1 [translate]="'title'"></h1>
```

We can also pass a `parameter`.

```
<h1>{{'text' | translate:{'value':'ngx-translate'} }}</h1>
```

OR

```
<h1 [translate]="'text'" [translateParams]="{value: 'ngx-translate'}"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending a lot of time with this exact problem, I found the solution on this github thread: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/574

Specifically this solved the problem:

> Only the page that is changing the language needs to have the second loader in it:
>   (TranslateModule.forChild({...}). All other pages just need >TranslateModule.forChild()

So you have to add in [your-lang-changing-page].module.ts the same content you wrote in app.module.ts, this time for the child:

Used version:

- angular: 5.2.10
- ngx-translate: 9.1.1
- ionic: 3.2

Example where I change language on first app start via buttons "tutorial.module.ts":

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TutorialPage } from './tutorial';
import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {createTranslateLoader} from "../../app/app.module";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TutorialPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TutorialPage),
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    TutorialPage
  ]
})
export class TutorialPageModule { }
```